# node.js & Express / Read stream and write to client

Tags: node.js, express

I have the next code in the server side:

```
client.getFile(url.substring(1, url.length), function (err, res) {
 var outputStream1 = fs.createWriteStream("./tmp/" + url);
 res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    outputStream1.write(chunk);
                });
  res.on('end', function () {
                    outputStream1.end();
                    // I got the response in the parameters function. It refer to the res express param
                    response.setHeader("content-type", 'application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8');
                    response.setHeader("content-type", 'application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8');
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="' + fileName + '"' + "; filename*=UTF-8''" + fileName + "");
                    var readStream = fs.createReadStream("./tmp/" + url);
                    fs.stat("./tmp/" + url, function(error, stat) {
                        console.log("The size of the file is: " + stat.size);
                    })
                    readStream.on('open', function () {
                        readStream.pipe(response);
                    });
                    readStream.on('end', function () {
                        response.end();
                    });
```

and the output is: `The size of the file is: 5992213`

Now I sent the request from the server to the client, and want to save it into file, so I do the next in the CLIENT side:

```
  var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("C://Client//create.pdf");
        fs.stat("C://ClientFile//something5.pdf", function(error, stat) {
        res.pipe(writeStream);
    });
```

But I see that the file which save is `10.4 MB`, and when I open it, the next error is shown:"File is out of memory"

What I do wrong?

Comment: Your solution is overthinking, in my opinion.
to download the file on client site you should use http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.download

Comment: @cieszynka: It says `TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'download'`

Answer (score 1):

In your router, set url to download the file

```
app.get('/url-to-file.pdf', callback);
```

and then, in callback function use res.download, like this:

```
callback = function(req, res){
            res.download('server/path/to/file');
        }
```

You can write this as

```
app.get('/url-to-file.pdf', function(req, res){
            res.download('server/path/to/file');
        });
```

on client site just run the url : domain/url-to-file.pdf

most problems, in this solution, can be dynamic generation of the url

Comment: instead of a file that is saved in the server, how can I fetch from another third party REST API and serve to client?